# Custom event handler in v node data object

Tags: vue.js

In my child component I have an custom click handler that emits an event like this:

```
this.$emit('nextslide');
```

And in my parent component I try to catch the event like this:

```
render(createElement) {
    return createElement(
        'div',
        {
            on: {
                nextslide: this.triggerFunction,
            }
        },

        this.$slots.default,
    )
},
```

I get no errors at all but it is also not working. I'm wondering if you can actually catch and event like this.

The page:

```
<carousel>
    <slide-next>
    </slide-next>
</carousel>
```

`Carousel.vue`:

```
<script>
    export default {

        render(createElement) {
            return createElement(
                'div',
                {
                    on: {
                        nextslide: this.triggerFunction,
                    }
                },
                this.$slots.default,
            )
        },

        methods: {
            triggerFunction() {
                console.log('this should trigger');
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

`SlideNext.vue`

```
<script>
    export default {

        render(createElement) {
            return createElement(
                'div',
                {
                    on: {
                        click: this.clickHandler
                    },

                },
                'Next')
        },

        methods: {

          clickHandler() {
              this.$emit('nextslide');
              console.log('trigger emit');
          },

        },

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So you want in parent component, to listen to event created in child component.Take a look here: [See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/e4bfedx3/)

**Child component:**

```
Vue.component('child-component', {
    data: function() {
    return {
        text: 'hi i am a text from child component'
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h('div', {
        class: ['text'],
      on: {
        click: this.clicked
      }
    },
    ['Click me,please']
    )
  },
  methods: {
    clicked() {
        this.$emit('click', this.text)
    }
  }
})
```

**Parent component:**

```
Vue.component('parent-component', {
    render (h) {
    return h('child-component', {
        on: {
        click: this.clicked
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    clicked(data_passed_from_child) {
        alert(`From child passed: ${data_passed_from_child}`)
    }
  }
})
```

And finally to make this to work:

```
<div id="app">
  <parent-component></parent-component>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

Comment: This works! but how do I return more child components?

Comment: I answer your question and you have to appreciete this i think.Anyway you can take a look here for another questions: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Comment: I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

You're registering the listener on a `<div>` element instead of the component. Component events do not bubble, unlike native DOM events, so you can only register the `nextslide` event on the child component vnode directly instead of an ancestor.

I can't see from your example where the relationship between the parent and child component is – your parent component isn't rendering the child component directly (unless it's in the default slot).

Comment: Ah makes sense... Yes my child component is in the default slot. I am not clear on the "so you can only register the nextslide event on the child component vnode directly" do I have to move my `triggerFunction` to my child component instead?

Comment: All I meant by that was you can only have the `{ on: { nextslide: this.triggerFunction } }` bit for the child component (whatever that is) and not a `'div'`.

Comment: I edited my question with the components, would you mind to take a look and help me with how I can achieve this?